# Unfortunately, [appname] has stopped Error

Tags: android

I am a newbie in developing an android application. I've been reading feeds from here and other sites to learn. When I click a button named Social, I am getting the Unfortunately [appname] has stopped. I am building an application and this is what I have:

MainActivity.java

```
Button btnOut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOut);
btnOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {      
    final Dialog alertbox = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        alertbox.setContentView(R.layout.button);
    alertbox.setTitle("News - Choose One:");
                Button world = (Button) alertbox.findViewById(R.id.world);
                world.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
                        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        setContentView(myWebView);
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://news.yahoo.com/world");
                    }
                });  
                Button tech = (Button) alertbox.findViewById(R.id.tech);
                tech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
                        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        setContentView(myWebView);
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://news.yahoo.com/tech");
                    }
                });  
                Button sport = (Button) alertbox.findViewById(R.id.sport);
                sport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview2);
                        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                        setContentView(myWebView);
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://sports.yahoo.com");
                    }
                });
                alertbox.show();
            }
        });
```

WebActivity2.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/webview2" >

</WebView>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nicx.amazing"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</manifest>
```

EDIT # 2 (Sorry I placed the wrong logcat before):
LOGCAT

```
04-09 20:04:40.348: W/dalvikvm(26501): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abc210)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at com.nicx.amazing.MainActivity$3$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:127)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the stack trace which can be found in your Logcat! Otherwise nobody will be able to help you without investing a unnecessary amount of time.

Comment: when debuggin android apps the logcat is essential. if you have not yet looked into it please do. if you have and still can't find your problem please add your logcat output to your question.

Comment: Look at the logcat messages and make yourself familiar with the debugger.

Comment: Quick look in your code: ``myWebView`.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` is this meant to be correct? I mean the ticks at myWebView variable (excuse the double ticks, but the formatter...)

Comment: _I've been reading feeds from here and other sites_ -- every one of those sites should have told you to examine your logcat for clues about app crashes. It doesn't help 100% of the time, but it's the most reliable information available most of the time.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning what my logcat says about this. I am testing using my phone (Sony Xperia Go - Android ICS). I updated my post and shown my logcat.

Comment: The most informative part is the one starting with `Caused by:`. It shows you the place in the code where the problem happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your culprit:

```
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 20:04:40.378: E/AndroidRuntime(26501):    at com.nicx.amazing.MainActivity$3$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:127)
```

in line 127 of MainActivity.java you got `null` argument value.

Comment: myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

this is my code in line 127. should i remove it?

Comment: No. You should ensure myWebView is not null